# how to use # in reqular expression in pup htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, expression

I need to use # in this regular expression but it make commented all characters after it ( #)

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9@#$&%_"'\{\}:\,\-]+)
```

can some one help me how can I use # not for comments...I used # but it doesn't work
thanks for any help.

Comment: Try escaping it with `\#`

Comment: `#` will never occur in the query string or path anyway. It starts the fragment identifier, which your webserver never sees.

Comment: thanks , I Used \# but it doesn't work. Can you help me more?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be over-escaping inside the second character class.

Check out the accepted answer to this SO question:

[htaccess regexp Underline and Space doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744455/htaccess-regexp-underline-and-space-doesnt-work)

Not knowing what the goal of this RewriteRule actually is makes it difficult to offer any further help. I would recommend looking into the RewriteRule flags to see if there is something useful you can leverage there, such as the noescape flag [NE]:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html